# Find the differential equation of all tangent lines of parabola $y^2=4x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

My professor said that it's $x(y')^2-yy'+1=0$ but how? I drew it and I think it open to the right $90^\circ$ but I can find the solution to differentiate

Comment: $y=4x$ is not a parabola.

Comment: sorry typo, thanks for noticing

Comment: @David after solving it like 4 times I got his answer, but I get your point. During examinations answers are not provided so the proof of 1-2+1=0 will not be in my head. Can you please do your solution easier to understand? if its ok...

Comment: @Mickey His **answer** is right - obviously, because you told us the answer.  But the method is wrong and will only give the right answer if you are lucky, or if you fake it.  Like you said, if the answer is not given, you won't think of $1-2+1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=4$$
and so
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac2y\ ,\quad y\ne0\ .$$
The tangent line when $y=b\ne0$ is
$$y-b=\frac2b\Bigl(x-\frac{b^2}4\Bigr)$$
which simplifies to
$$y=\frac2bx+\frac b2\ .\tag1$$
Hence the line satisfies
$$y'=\frac2b\ ;\tag2$$
combining with the previous equation,
$$y=y'x+\frac1{y'}$$
which simplifies to the equation you were given.

Comment: @Mickey The point is to find the equations of the lines in terms of a parameter - that's equation $(1)$ - then find the derivative - that's $(2)$ - then eliminate the parameter - in this case $b$.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating implicitly both sides to get: $2yy' = 4\Rightarrow 4y^2(y')^2=16\Rightarrow (y')^2 = \dfrac{4}{y^2}=\dfrac{1}{x}\Rightarrow x(y')^2 = 1$. Also: $yy'=\dfrac{4}{2}=2$,and since $1-2+1=0$, substituting we have: $x(y')^2-yy'+1=0$.

Comment: You could just as well say $3-2-1=0$, therefore $3x(y')^2-yy'-1=0$.  But this is not the right answer.  The method only shows that the parabola satisfies these DEs, not the tangent lines.